# Sharepoint 2010 Search File Share Returning Incorrect Results

Tags: 2010, search-results

Here's a weird one.  We are using Search on an Enterprise install of SP2010.  Content source is set to a specific folder in a file share and the search service account has read and execute access to all files and folders in that path.  I have scoped the entire content source as well a test scope for just .xls files under the content source.  All of the file names of interest have a sales order number in them so that is always my search criteria.

If I search for files with a number of 5xxxx in them which are all under a particular sub-folder, an exact match is made.  However, if I search for a number of 4xxxxx, I rarely (if ever) get a correct result and ususally no results.  The number exists in the file itself but search completly ignores the filename that has the number in it.  For instance, if I search for 413208 I get 0 results.  But, if I search for 413122 I get the file name `413208mg_shake%20software_re%20po#%603.xls` which is what I was looking for by searhing for the first number.  If I search for po#603 the correct result shows up but not 413208!?!

Can anyone give some suggestions as to what might be mixing up the results?  The only difference I can see is that the 5xxxx files have the sales order number in the middle of the file name versus the beginning. e.g. `FileOne_59311_D25.xls`?  Could it be special characters like spaces in the filename corrupt the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search with a '*' to ensure you get all results, for example:

the 413208mg_shake%20software_re%20po#%603.xls search can be returned via 413208mg or 413208*

Point of reference, it seems * can only be used at the end of a search term.

Comment: Thanks, @per and @zork!  Makes sense but I thought I'd tried an asterisk in my testing to no avail.  Tried it now and it does work using a test tool so I'll add it to my code.

Answer (score 4):

FileOne_59311_D25.xls has the word 59311 in the filename

413208mg_shake%20software_re%20po#%603.xls doesn't have the word 413208 in it (it has the word 413208mg, but that's not the same). It seems that it has 413122 somewhere in the content.